# How to use i2cset to display the ip address

Tags: bash, python

I am trying to use the `i2cset` command to display characters on my LCD screen. For example `i2cset -y 1 0x3e 0x40 0x49 displays I` and so on. Now I want to try and display my ip address. I had posted this question earlier in a forum where it was suggested that I could use the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP=$(hostname -I)

function hex()
{
printf "0x%02x\n" "'$1"
}

for i in "echo $IP | grep -o .";
do
hx=$(hex $i)
i2cset -y 1 0x3e 0x40 $hx
done
```

I execute the script using the command :

```
sudo bash -x ip.sh
```

ip.sh being the filename..

I get the following information printed on my laptop screen:

```
root@beaglebone:~# sudo bash -x ip.sh
++ hostname -I
+ IP='192.168.2.111 192.168.7.2 '
+ for i in '"echo $IP | grep -o ."'
++ hex echo 192.168.2.111 192.168.7.2 '|' grep -o .
++ printf '0x%02x\n' ''\''echo'
+ hx=0x65
+ i2cset -y 1 0x3e 0x40 0x65
```

### Updated Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP=$(hostname -I)

function hex()
{
printf "0x%02x\n" "'$1"

 }

for i in $(echo $IP | grep -o .)
hostname -I | while read -n1 i
do
  hx=$(hex $i)
  i2cset -y 1 0x3e 0x40 $hx
done
```

It gives an error now saying :
    try1.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `hostname'
    try1.sh: line 12:`hostname -I | while read -n1 i'

Kindly help.

Comment: How are you executing that script? The script runs fine on that part with `bash`, but with `sh`, it will give the error shown.

Comment: Is this a copy or a re-type? I ask, because it works for me - not that I have an LCD, but adding an echo to the `i2cset` line gives me a result - only one digit though.

Comment: @muru: I run it using the following command from the command line : 'sudo sh ip.sh'

Comment: @markwilliams: Yes. It is from somebody who suggessted this on a different forum..

Answer (score 0):

If you run the command as `sh ip.sh`, it will be run using `sh`, not with `bash` (making the shebang line pointless). Either run it with bash:

```
bash ip.sh
```

Or make it executable and run it directly:

```
./ip.sh
```

The traditional Bourne shell (`sh`) doesn't support the `function` keyword for [function definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05).

---

Aside from that, `"echo $IP | grep -o ."` doesn't run that command, it simply is that string. You need to do:

```
for i in $(echo $IP | grep -o .)
```

It might be easier to read in one character at a time:

```
hostname -I | while read -n1 i
do
    hx=$(hex $i)
    i2cset -y 1 0x3e 0x40 $hx
done
```

Comment: @NamitaRaju please edit your question to add more information. As you can see, that comment is barely readable.

Comment: I have edited the original question. Sorry for the unreadable comment previously!

Comment: @NamitaRaju see update.

Comment: I put in the code that you suggested so that the characters are read one at a time.. But now it gives me an error saying :                                                                ,`try1.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `hostname',
try1.sh: line 12: `hostname -I | while read -n1 i'.`

Comment: @NamitaRaju can you post the updated script?

Comment: kindly please look at my updated script.

Comment: @NamitaRaju That `while` loop is a full replacement for the `for` loop. Delete the `for` line and try.

Comment: That was so stupid of me!!! I replaced the for loop and it works perfectly!!! Thank you so much!! :)